# SWI Prolog mult every element of list

Tags: list, prolog, list-manipulation

I want to write a predicate that will be taking every element from my list and mult with others without duplicates.

Examples:

```
?- predicate([2,3,5,6],X).
X = [6,10,12,15,18,30].        % expected result

?- predicate([1,6,10],X).
X = [6,10,60].                 % expected result
```

I was trying something like this, but I don't know how to upgrade this code:

```
predicate([],[]).
predicate([_|[]],[]) :-
    !.
predicate([H,S|T],[V|X]) :-
    V is H*S,
    predicate([H|T],X).
```

Comment: I take it your given list doesn't have duplicates? Like `[2,2,3]`?

Answer (score 1):

The following gives the results you describe:

```
predicate(Xs, Ys):-
  aggregate_all(
    set(Y),
    (
      member(X1, Xs),
      member(X2, Xs),
      X1 =\= X2,
      Y is X1 * X2
    ),
    Ys
  ).
```

Notice that `aggregate_all/3` is a non-standard predicate from [library `aggregate`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate). There are alternative implementations that use the ISO predicate `bagof/3`.